# How to choose the best fit frame in arkit

Tags: swift, arkit, render-to-texture

I'm working on a 3D scanning function, and he needs to get real textures. I'm going to do it with ARkit.
I've got the ARMeshAnchor and so about his current frame (converted to UIImage)

```
struct AFrame {
    var capturedImage: UIImage?
    var timestamp: TimeInterval
    var camera: ARCamera
}

struct TextureData {

    var anchor: ARMeshAnchor 
    var frames: [AFrame]

    mutating func updateTexture(frame:ARFrame) {
        self.frames.append(AFrame(capturedImage: getTextureImage(frame: frame)?.compressImageMid(maxLength: 512*512), timestamp: frame.timestamp, camera: frame.camera))
    }
    func getTextureImage(frame: ARFrame) -> UIImage? {

        let pixelBuffer = frame.capturedImage
        let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        let context = CIContext(options:nil)
        guard let cameraImage = context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent) else {return nil}
        return UIImage(cgImage: cameraImage)
    }
    
}
```

Because the range of ARMeshAnchor may have exceeded a single frame, one ARMeshAnchor corresponds to multiple frames in TextureData. and I generate a SCNNode object for an ARMeshAnchor

```
    func addNode(texture:TextureData) {
        let anchor = texture.anchor
        let aTrans = SCNMatrix4(anchor.transform)
        
        let geom = SCNGeometry(geometry: anchor.geometry, modelMatrix: anchor.transform, needTexture: true)
//        geom.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = texture.capturedImage ???
        let meshNode = SCNNode(geometry: geom)
        meshNode.simdTransform = anchor.transform
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.scanNode.addChildNode(meshNode)
        }
    }
```

The problem I am currently encountering is how to use the correct frame according to the position of the faces provided by ARMeshAnchor. Or, how to use multiple pictures to add texture to a SCNGeometry

I have tried to get the current anchor from each frame (the system provides this method), and then use the faces of each anchor as a SCNNode to produce textures.
This method is logically possible, but there will be serious performance problems. Because thousands of SCNNodes will be created

```
for f in 0..<faces.count {
            let face = face(at: f, faces: faces)            
            for frame in texture.frames {
                for fv in face {
                    let vert = vertex(at: UInt32(fv), vertices: vertices)
                    let vTrans = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(vert[0], vert[1], vert[2])
                    let wTrans = SCNMatrix4Mult(vTrans, aTrans)
                    let wPos = SCNVector3(wTrans.m41, wTrans.m42, wTrans.m43)
                    fVerts.append(wPos)

    //                        let norm = normal(at: UInt32(fv), normals: normals)
    //                        let nTrans = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(norm[0], norm[1], norm[2])
    //                        let wNTrans = SCNMatrix4Mult(nTrans, aTrans)
    //                        let wNPos = SCNVector3(wNTrans.m41, wTrans.m42, wNTrans.m43)
    //                        fNorms.append(wNPos)

                    // here's where you would find the frame that best fits
                    // for simplicity, just use the last frame here
                    let tCoord = getTextureCoord(camera: frame.camera, vert: vert, aTrans: anchor.transform)
                    tCoords.append(tCoord)
                }
            }
            let vertsSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: fVerts)
            let facesSource = SCNGeometryElement(indices: [UInt32(0), UInt32(1), UInt32(2)], primitiveType: .triangles)
            let textrSource = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: tCoords)
            let geom = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertsSource,textrSource], elements: [facesSource])
            geom.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = texture.capturedImage
            let meshNode = SCNNode(geometry: geom)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.scanNode.addChildNode(meshNode)
            }
        }
}
```